# The Data on the United Nations General Debate text

Tags: international-relations, united-nations, data-sources

I'm searching for the text of United Nations General Debate, which is the set of annual speeches by each country. I found some text on the recent General Debate (back to 2011) [here](http://gadebate.un.org/sessions-archive), but I would like to collect older data as well.

Comment: The search feature at UN site is indeed very limited. Including the absence of context search.

Answer (score 3):

The UN document and search system takes a bit of getting used to, but the meeting records for each of the General Assembly debates are all available online. The UN has published the document reference for each General Debate meeting record [here](https://ask.un.org/faq/154658), from the first session in 1946 up to the seventy-sixth in 2021.

The full list of speeches can be searched for on the [UN digital library](https://digitallibrary.un.org/?ln=en) with the query `agenda:(general debate) NOT documentsymbol:"A/C.*"`, which returns all records from the general debate but excludes those made in committees. You can then filter by year and by resource type on the left-hand side. If you go specifically to the ['speeches' search page](https://digitallibrary.un.org/search?cc=Speeches&ln=en&c=Speeches) before using the query above, you also get the option to filter by country and subject

Answer (score 1):

2010: http://gadebate.un.org/sessions-archive/65
2009: http://www.un.org/en/ga/64/generaldebate/2309.shtml

See more going back to 1999 listed on the left at http://www.un.org/en/ga/sessions/.